# how to show json response data in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

i am trying to get url information through get_meta_tags though laravel and want to show in my angularjs application.
but the problem is response return in

```
Array
(
    [title] => Mercy Badshah Full HD
    [description] => mercy badsah
    [keywords] => mercy, badshah new song, badshah songs, badshah, badshah mercy
    [theme-color] => #e62117
    [twitter:card] => player
    [twitter:site] => @youtube
    [twitter:url] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoXZ2YgnME
    [twitter:title] => Mercy Badshah Full HD
    [twitter:description] => mercy badsah
    [twitter:image] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QyoXZ2YgnME/maxresdefault.jpg
    [twitter:app:name:iphone] => YouTube
    [twitter:app:id:iphone] => 544007664
    [twitter:app:name:ipad] => YouTube
    [twitter:app:id:ipad] => 544007664
    [twitter:app:url:iphone] => vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoXZ2YgnME&feature=applinks
    [twitter:app:url:ipad] => vnd.youtube://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoXZ2YgnME&feature=applinks
    [twitter:app:name:googleplay] => YouTube
    [twitter:app:id:googleplay] => com.google.android.youtube
    [twitter:app:url:googleplay] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyoXZ2YgnME
    [twitter:player] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/QyoXZ2YgnME
    [twitter:player:width] => 1280
    [twitter:player:height] => 720
    [attribution] => SonyBMG
)
```

this format. 
data shows only title, description, keywords and theme-color. when i put other parameter like `{{urlDetails.twitter:image}}` shows error

> Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the
>   expression [urlDetails.twitter:image!=''] starting at [:image!=].
>   please help me out for this error. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object has a property with non alphanumeric or non-underscore characters, as is the case with the property `"twitter:image"`, then you need to use the square bracket notation to access it:

```
{{urlDetails['twitter:image']}}
```

Rule of thumb: if your property is a literal value that could also be a valid variable name, use dot notation; otherwise, use square bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

The data representation you have provided in the question is array. So get the data through array subscripts. If the array name is urlDetails then retrieve data by urlDetails['twitter:image'].

Comment: Minor clarification: the OP's snippet was likely from PHP (specifically, the output of [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)), so the data might be considered an "Array" on the PHP side, but only because PHP uses that term for its key-value data structure. When it arrives on the client-side & the JSON has been parsed, it's more accurate to call it an object, from JavaScript's perspective.

Comment: @tavnab ok, I got it